# UISearchBar not showing on device but is showing in simulator

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I have a table view that I have added a search controller in to by putting the following in to my table views class which I made sure to add `UISearchBarDelegate` in the class definition.

`let searchDisplay = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)`

Then in my viewDidLoad function I entered this:

```
searchDisplay.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchDisplay.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
definesPresentationContext = true
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchDisplay.searchBar
```

I then have functions that get the required data depending on what has been searched.

Also added this after the class but in the same file:

```
extension AllTableViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating{
    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchDisplay: UISearchController) {
        filterContentForSearchText(searchDisplay.searchBar.text!)
    }
}
```

As I say in the title the code all seems to run swimmingly in the Simulator but when I run it on a device the search bar just doesn't appear. No different messages appear in the output box so I don't really know where to start.

Comment: Have you tried a `sizeToFit` call on the search bar?

Comment: wow, thanks. How did I miss that, was searching for ages and I didn't even consider it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried a sizeToFit call on the search bar? – keithbhunter Jun 30 at 13:43